# After removal of the load the new image, it appears the previous image - jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload

After removal of the load the new image, it appears the previous image (was removed).  
How do to clear the cache or cookie in jquery or php? Should there be to appear the new picture.

See picture:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your images being cached you can append server side a random string to your images SRC:

```
<img src="images/image.jpg?5888279301" alt="Hello Areku" />
```

or a server time string